# Evernote, sample "Hello World" code error using Visual Studio 10 WebForm

Tags: evernote

I am using a Visual Studio 2010 WebForm application to post a simple note to EverNote using the sample code for "Hello world.   Here is the Code:

```
    private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       ENNote myPlainNote = new ENNote();
       ENSession.SetSharedSessionDeveloperToken(
       "My Developer 
       Token","https://www.evernote.com/shard/s308/notestore");
       myPlainNote.Title = "My First Notes";
       myPlainNote.Content = ENNoteContent.NoteContentWithString("Hello 
       World!);
      ENNoteRef myPlainNoteRef = 
      ENSession.SharedSession.UploadNote(myPlainNote, null);
    }
```

I get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" on the last line. I would really appreciate if someone could guide this newbie to resolve this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Just an update. I replaced the Developer Token line with ENSession.SetSharedSessionConsumerKey("my key", "my secret");
Now the application runs without error but no notes exists when I point my browser to https://sandbox.evernote.com.

Answer (score 0):

**UploadNote** requires a second parameter to indicate in which notebook you want the new note created.

You can pass it an **ENNotebook**; for example, you could get such an object like this:

```
List<ENNotebook> myNotebookList = ENSession.SharedSession.ListNotebooks();
ENNotebook desiredNotebook = myNotebookList.Find(i => i.Name == "The name of my desired notebook");
```

You should also be able to pass a second parameter of **null** to add the note to your default notebook.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I found out the problem was to do with the firewall or proxy server at work. Tried at home and it worked. This is a show stopper for me as the application is work related.